# How do I assign an action to long pressing the home button?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-5, tasker, xposed-framework, home-button, macrodroid

I want to fix it so the home button long press kills a particular app. I can't see the option for home long press in Tasker or Macrodroid.

Galaxy S5, rooted, CM Marshmallow, Xposed installed.

Comment: [Xposed Additions](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.spazedog.xposed.additionsgb) allows modifying long-press behaviour, but executing more complicated actions is a bit out of it...

Comment: Additions can execute Tasker actions, so this gets me close. However, tasker won't kill the app successfully

Answer (score 0):

Macrodroid doesn't offer an action based on  home key trigger. Macrodroid developer in app forums [says](https://www.tapatalk.com/groups/macrodroid/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=2823)

> It's impossible to create such a trigger because the home button is a fundamental part of the OS and there is no way to intercept the button press.

I don't know  Tasker, but guess the same limitations would apply, so you would need to find an alternative way. One method below:

Since you are on CM, you can use [Gravity Box](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.ceco.marshmallow.gravitybox) Xposed module

**To kill foreground app**

Navigation keys action → Home key → long press action → Kill foreground application

**To kill a particular app** - combination of Gravity Box and Macrodroid

Navigation keys action → Home key → long press action → Custom actions → toggle *applications* to reveal *shortcuts* → Macrodroid Shortcuts → Add new macro

Trigger → Empty Trigger

Action : Kill application → choose application from drop down menu

Comment: If your ROM offers you navigation bar, you can add a custom key from navigation bar tweaks and assign similarly